# SQL subquery task

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I'm trying to solve the following task.

> The following data definition defines an organization's employee
>   hierarchy.
>
> An employee is a manager if any other employee has their managerId set
>   to the first employees id. An employee who is a manager may or may not
>   also have a manager.

```
TABLE employees   
 id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 managerId INTEGER REFERENCES employees(id)   
 name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
```

> Write a query that selects the names of employees who are not
>   managers.

I have tried:

```
SELECT name FROM employees where id NOT IN (SELECT managerId FROM employees)
```

which does not give desired result. What's wrong?

Comment: This is strange, I would think it works. Can you provide sample data and show what it returns that you dont want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding ManagerID is not null as a where condition, it prevents nulls from coming back and messing up your intended use of the NOT IN.

```
SELECT name
FROM employees
where id NOT IN (
    SELECT managerId FROM employees where managerId is not null
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`NOT IN` will not work if the subquery returns `null` :

So, i would use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` :

```
SELECT e.name 
FROM employees e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employees ee WHERE ee.managerId = e.id);
```